# Install new relic Django 1.5 in virtualenv with supervisord

Tags: django, virtualenv, newrelic, supervisord

I've a completely good running Django site on a production server with Django 1.5 inside a virtualenv and controlled with supervisord.

I cannot however get the new relic monitoring going. Everything starts fine, but my application is not showing in the new relic dashboard.

here is my supervisor config:

```
[program:<PROJECTNAME>]
process_name=gunicorn
directory=/var/www/<PROJECTNAME>/<PROJECTNAME>
environment= 
    DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE='settings.prod',
    SECRET_KEY='xxx',
    DB_USER='xxx',
    DB_PASSWD='xxx',
    NEW_RELIC_CONFIG_FILE="/var/www/<PROJECTNAME>/newrelic.ini"
command=/var/www/<PROJECTNAME>/env/bin/newrelic-admin run-program /var/www/<PROJECTNAME>/env/bin/gunicorn wsgi:application -c  /var/www/<PROJECTNAME>/<PROJECTNAME>/gunicorn_settings.py
group=www-data
autostart=True
stdout_logfile = /var/log/webapps/<PROJECTNAME>/gunicorn.log
logfile_maxbytes = 100MB
redirect_stderr=True
```

And this is the gunicorn_settings config file:

```
pythonpath = '/var/www/<PROJECTNAME>/'
pidfile = '/tmp/<PROJECTNAME>.pid'
user = 'www-data'
group = 'www-data'
proc_name = '<PROJECTNAME'
workers = 2
bind = 'unix:/tmp/gunicorn-<PROJECTNAME>.sock'
stdout_logfile = '/var/log/gunicorn/<PROJECTNAME>.log'
loglevel = 'debug'
debug = True
```

wsgi.py contains an extra pythonpath /var/www/

I've another Django 1.2 site running inside a virtualenv with supervisor and new relic on the same server just fine.

Comment: New Relic does have some known issues with running gunicorn in daemon mode or gevent mode (see https://newrelic.com/docs/python/status-of-python-agent). Are you using one of those? You can always open a ticket with New Relic support as well, if you want them to look more specifically into your environment and what could be causing this issue.

Comment: No, I am not using gevent or daemon mode. The same config works for django 1.2.